# CMD with % and ^

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have a file.bat which I run via command-line in Windows.

It need to read some characters like `%` and `^` for the password.

When I run the script, I see that the shell does not read these characters.

What can I do to fix this??

Comment: How do you read the password? With `set /p` or as a paramter to your batch?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to escape these with a `^`.

To escape `^` you use another `^^`

As jeb correctly pointed out you can't escape `%`'s on the command line, but when setting variables with them in the variable string it seems to accept them.

```
set p=hello%
echo %p%
hello%
```

Comment: To escape `%` inside a batch file you use `%%`. On the command line you can't really escape them

Comment: Oh right, I thought you could on command line, I didn't know that.

Comment: the `^` trick does work for `%` from the command line - http://pastebin.com/itcV7Vqw

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set var=something
for /f "delims=" %%a ("!var!") do
(
  endlocal 
  set "result=%%~a"
)
```

This will let the command prompt read the special characters from **var** - [source](http://ss64.org/viewtopic.php?id=1460)